# heading problem H1 in CSS

Tags: css

I'm not able to change the size and color of heading h1 in my site.

I have used an external Css file.

code as below..

```
h1 {
    Background-color : red;
    Color : green;
}
```

Comment: How does your HTML document look like?

Comment: Incidentally, really really, bad idea to use red and green like that. Not only looks awful, but about 5% (maybe more) of your visitors probably won't be able to see it properly. Oh, and you'll fail the accessibility test.

Comment: I also thought that maybe having capitals was a problem, but it seems to work no worries on my machine. Have you tested using more than one browser? Have you tested using *just* that css and an almost blank HTML document?

Comment: I have used mam.....all the options.

acttualy i'm new to the css...I'm just trying to implement that..
I'm not going to usein aany website.It just a test.

Answer (score 4):

An URL would be helpful.

Also, CSS rules are lowercase. (e.g. background-color, not Background-color)

Read about CSS specifity, that is probably the problem: http://htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/

Answer (score 3):

Try using Firebug or IE8 Developer Tools to inspect the element and make sure you don't have conflicting styles from another stylesheet or somewhere else in your html document.

Answer (score 3):

Thats looks ok to me.

You may have an issue with the H1 already being set somewhere else in the style sheet.

Either you can search for it or make your adjustments as important ie.

```
h1{
  background-color: #ff0000 !important;
  color: #00FF00 !important;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try setting '!important' behind it:

```
color: green !important;
```

Note that this only applies if there are other styles overriding your external css. You should test that your external CSS-file is read at all. You can do that by making a new paragraph for example. Give it an id (id="foo") and set this in your css

```
color: green;
```

If it doesn't turn green you should check your css include path.

Comment: Ok, then it has to be the path to your stylesheet that is wrong. How are you linking to the stylesheet? If you are not using an absolute path (including http:// etc) try that. You should check that you can reach this URL by pasting it in your browser. It should show a text representation of your css file.

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider using the hex codes for the colors instead of "red" and "green" - I've seen that produce some odd behaviors in some browsers (or be ignored entirely).

Answer (score 0):

```
h1 {
    background: red !important;
    color: green !important;
}
```

Also, depending on how your original h1 declaration was written, you can use [specificity](http://htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/) and [cascading](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html) to overwrite the previous value(s).

Answer (score 0):

Also, consider the ordering that you call your external stylesheets, you may have a your main css file appear first, and then a second stylesheet after that, which also has styles set on your H1, this may be overriding your first stylesheet - something to look into anyways.

Comment: ni sir till i'm having only 1 style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've verified that the external stylesheet is loaded to your site and you are referencing it properly.

Answer (score 0):

One way you will get this problem is if your css files is in subfolder say `styles` or `styles\pages` and you are not providing the full relative path.

say if the site.css file is in styles folder.

This will *not* load the style (because the path is provided and file is not in root)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site.css" media="screen" />
```

This will load it correctly.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/site.css" media="screen" />
```